# Lucene 4.2.1 WhiteSpaceAnalyzer

Tags: lucene, analyzer

I have a code that works fine with Luce 3.6. I just upgraded to Lucene 4.2.1 and I am having a hard type to use WhiteSpaceAnalyzer (also StandardAnalyzer and WhiteSpaceTokenizer). It gives me "WhiteSpaceAnalyzer cannot be resolved to a type" error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Couple likely possibilities:

- Seeing some possible overzealous CamelCaseIng, although decent chance it's not reproduced in your code, but it's: [`WhitespaceAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html)
- It's moved from: `org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer` to `org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer`.  Check your imports.
- They finally removed the deprecated no-arg constructor.  You'll need to pass a [Version](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/Version.html) to [the constructor](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html#WhitespaceAnalyzer%28org.apache.lucene.util.Version%29) now.